# How to dispatch multiple ngrx actions at the same time

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using ngrx and have a scenerio where I need to dispatch 2 actions at the same time.  My state has properties for updating and updated and looks like below.

```
//from reducer
const defaultCardState: CardState = {
    ids: [],
    entities: {},
    loaded: false,
    loading: false,
    adding: false,
    added: false,
    updating: false,
    updated: false,
    deleting: false,
    deleted: false
};
```

These are the actions I'm dispatching from my component

```
this.store.dispatch(fromCard.updateCard({id: id1, changes: {name: name1}}))
this.store.dispatch(fromCard.updateCard({id: id2, changes: {name: name2}}))
```

Below are my action, reducer and effect

```
//Update Card Actions
export const updateCard = createAction('[Cards] Update Card', props<{id: string, changes: any}>())
export const updateCardSuccess = createAction('[Cards] Update Card Success', props<{changes: any}>());
export const updateCardFail = createAction('[Cards] Update Card Fail')

//Reducer
on(fromCards.updateCard, (state) => ({...state, updating: true, updated: false})),
    on(fromCards.updateCardSuccess, (state, action: any) => ({...cardAdapter.updateOne(action.changes, state), updated: true, updating: false})),
    on(fromCards.updateCardFail, (state, action: any) => fromCards.updateCardFail),

//Update Card Effect
updateCard$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromCardActions.updateCard),
    map((action: any) => { return {id: action.id, changes: action.changes}}),
    switchMap((action: any) => this.cardService.updateCard(action).pipe(
        map((res) => (fromCardActions.updateCardSuccess({changes: action }))),
        catchError(() => of(fromCardActions.updateCardFail))
    ))
))
```

What is the best way to dispatch these actions one after the other so the updating and updated fields don't conflict?  If I run just one of these it works but if I dispatch them both together like shown above, only one completes.  I see that both actions get dispatched but only one success action gets dispatched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dispatch multiple action in your effect and I would recommend you do that only in the effect

Consider example below

```
@Effect()
dispatchMultiAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<SomeAction.Dispatch>(someActions.Dispatch),
    switchMap(_ =>
        of(
            new someActions.InitData(),
            new someActions.GetData(),
            new someActions.LoadData()
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: It's cleaner to do this using `mergeMap`.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to Tony's answer, but using the correct operator:

```js
@Effect()
dispatchMultiAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<SomeAction.Dispatch>(someActions.Dispatch),
    mergeMap(_ => [
            new someActions.InitData(),
            new someActions.GetData(),
            new someActions.LoadData()
        ])
    )
);
```

Comment: is there a reason you didn't use the "of" operator.  I can't figure out why it is sometimes used to dispatch actions and sometimes not.

Comment: You might consider reading from learnrxjs. They have very good descriptions for each operator.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand what the of operator does but I’m unsure why sometimes the action is dispatched as an observable like Tony shows above and sometimes not like in your example

Comment: The only reason Tony used `of([])` is because `switchMap` will only return one observable. Essentially, what he's done is a workaround to return multiple actions. However, using `mergeMap` we can return multiple actions properly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't, you have a different action with a payload that takes an array of cards instead of a single card and then the reducer returns the new state updated with the multiple cards. Your api should also be able to take an array so your effect can send multiple to the server.

Comment: Thanks! So I would create a service that accepts an array and would make n number of calls to the backend to make the changes?

Comment: The point of making your api accept an array is so you can bulk update in a single call rather than round tripping the server.

Answer (score 2):

Using an action to dispatch multiple other actions is bad practice, since this increases your application's complexity. As your app grows, it gets increasingly harder to debug actions and reason about their origin.
This talk from Mike Ryan describes Good Action Hygiene with NgRx:
https://youtu.be/JmnsEvoy-gY?t=285

Comment: Linking to a YouTube video is not an acceptable answer. It is fine for a comment but it is not an answer. At least explain the contents of what is in the video and then link to the video as a reference.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Thank you for your advice. I changed my answer. I shared this link because I think It is very important video to understand the architecture of actions in ngrx.

Comment: Thanks! The video was actually pretty eye-opening.  I have been reusing actions and have seen some of the pitfalls from that.  So he mentions that unique event actions create more actions but they'll create equally as many effects and reducers too right?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to xandermonkey's answer, but using the correct operator:

```
@Effect()
dispatchMultiAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<SomeAction.Dispatch>(someActions.Dispatch),
    concatMap(_ => [
            new someActions.InitData(),
            new someActions.GetData(),
            new someActions.LoadData()
        ])
    )
);
```

Note the difference between concatMap and mergeMap. Because concatMap does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes, the value from the source delayed by 2000ms will be emitted first. Contrast this with mergeMap which subscribes immediately to inner observables, the observable with the lesser delay (1000ms) will emit, followed by the observable which takes 2000ms to complete.