# How to dispatch multiple actions from single effects in NgRx?

Tags: angular, redux, angular8, ngrx

My current effect code is  like that here is my effect code in which currently i am dispatching single action from effect. But i want to dispatch one more action notificationNew() which i have commented in below effect code.

```
    bookPropertyRequest$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequest),
        concatMap(action =>
            this.ReservationReqService.sendReservationRequest(action.reservationRequest).pipe(
                map(response => {
                    if (response.status) {
                        this.helperService.snackbar('Request Sent.');
                        // Here i want to dispatch another action - notificationNew()
                        return ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequestSuccess({ reservationRequest: response.result });
                    } else {
                        const errorCode = response.errorCode;
                        if (errorCode !== null) {
                            this.helperService.errorAlert('', response.message, 'error');
                            return ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequestFailure({
                                error: {
                                    type: response.errorCode || null,
                                    message: response.message
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }),
                catchError(error => EMPTY)
            )
        )
    );
});

Now I want to dispatch another action from action notificationNew() when the above-mentioned effect is success. So my my concern is how we can dispatch multiple actions from single effect.
```

So how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dispatch multiple ngrx actions at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090360/how-to-dispatch-multiple-ngrx-actions-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` in place of `map` operator, to be able to return an `array` of actions, which will then emit each action :

```js
... 
this.ReservationReqService.sendReservationRequest(action.reservationRequest).pipe(
  switchMap(response => {
    if (response.status) {
      this.helperService.snackbar('Request Sent.');
      return [
        ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequestSuccess({ reservationRequest: response.result }),
        UiActions.notificationNew({...})
      ]
...
```

#### Suggestion

Here is a proposition of refactoring with less code :

```js
bookPropertyRequest$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequest),
    concatMap(action =>
      this.reservationReqService.sendReservationRequest(action.reservationRequest).pipe(
        switchMap(response => [
          ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequestSuccess({ reservationRequest: response.result }),
          UiActions.notificationNew({...})
        ]),
        catchError(errorResponse => [
          ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequestFailure({
            error: errorResponse.error
          }),
          UiActions.errorAlert(errorResponse.error.message);
        ])
      )
    );
  ));
```

To do that, you need to return the "classic" response with `HttpClient` inside your `sendReservationRequest` method:

```js
sendReservationRequest(request: ReservationRequest) {
  return this.httpClient.post(SERVICE_URL);
  // no {observe: 'response'} here
}
```

**Note**: Very simple in this example, but maybe in some situation it could be necessary to test `errorResponse` content inside `catchError`. To avoid any issue with `errorResponse.error.message`... Out of topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this kind of problems with an other effect, where i filter for the success Action:

```
    notificationNew$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ReservationReqActions.bookPropertyRequestSuccess),
        map((action)=> ReservationReqActions.notificationNew(action.payload) )
```

So it is clear structured and the code is not too complicated.